# Search elements of a single character string in a dataframe column to subset it

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I have two dataframes:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(k1 = "AFD(1);Acf(2);Vgr7(2);"
                  ,k2 = "ABC(7);BHG(46);TFG(675);")

df2 <- data.frame(site =c("AFD(1);AFD(2);", "Acf(2);", "TFG(677);", 
"XX(275);",  "ABC(7);", "ABC(9);")
                  ,p1 = rnorm(6, mean = 5, sd = 2)
                  ,p2 = rnorm(6, mean = 6.5, sd = 2))
```

The first dataframe is in fact a list of often very long strings, made of 'elements". Each "element" is made of a few letters/numbers, followed by a number in brackets, followed by a semicolon. In this example I only put 3 "elements" into each string, but in my real dataframe there are tens to hundreds of them.

```
> df1
                      k1                       k2
1 AFD(1);Acf(2);Vgr7(2); ABC(7);BHG(46);TFG(675);
```

The second dataframe shares some of the "elements" with `df1`. Its first column, called `site`, contains some (not all) "elements" from the first dataframe, sometimes the "element" forms the whole string, and sometimes is a part of a longer string:

```
> df2
            site       p1       p2
1 AFD(1);AFD(2); 4.043700 3.745881
2        Acf(2); 5.835883 5.670011
3      TFG(677); 7.717359 5.711420
4       XX(275); 4.794425 6.381373
5        ABC(7); 5.775343 8.700051
6        ABC(9); 4.892390 8.026351
```

I would like to filter the whole `df2` using `df2$site` and each `k` column from `df1` (there are many K columns, not all of them contain `k` in the names).

The easiest way to explain this is to show how the desired output would look like.

```
> outcome
    k   site            p1          p2
1   k1  AFD(1);AFD(2):  4.043700    3.745881
2   k1  Acf(2);         5.835883    5.670011
3   k2  ABC(7);         5.775343    8.700051
```

The first column of the `outcome` dataframe corresponds to the column names in `df1`. The second column corresponds to the `site` column of `df2` and contains only `sites` from `df1` columns that were found in `df2$sites`. Other columns are from `df2`.

I appreciate that this question is made of two separate "problems", one grepping-related and one related to looping through `df1` columns. I decided to show the task in its entirety in case there exists a solution that addresses both in one go.

##### FAILED SOLUTION 1

I can create a string to grep, but for each column separately:

```
# this replaces the semicolons with "|", but does not escape the brackets.
k1_pattern <- df1 %>% 
  select(k1) %>% 
  deframe() %>% 
  str_replace_all(";","|")
```

And then I am not sure how to use it. This (below) didn't work, maybe because I didn't escape brackets, but I am struggling with doing it:

```
k1_result <- df2 %>% 
  filter(grepl(pattern = k1_pattern, site))
```

But even if it did work, it would only deal with a single column from `df1`, and I have many, and would like to perform this operation on all `df1` columns at the same time.

##### FAILED SOLUTION 2

I can create a list of `sites` to search in `df2` from columns in `df1`:

```
k1_sites<- df1 %>% 
  select(k1) %>% 
  deframe() %>% 
  strsplit(., "[;]") %>% 
  unlist()
```

but the delimiter is lost here, and `%in%` cannot be used, as the match will sometimes be partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way going to a long format for exact matching (so no regex):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1_long = df1 |> stack() |>
  separate_rows(values, sep = ";") |>
  filter(values != "")

df2 |>
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  separate_rows(site, sep = ";") |>
  filter(site != "") |>
  left_join(df1_long, by = c("site" = "values")) %>%
  group_by(id) |>
  filter(any(!is.na(ind))) %>%
  summarize(
    site = paste(site, collapse = ";"),
    across(-site, \(x) first(na.omit(x)))
  )
# # A tibble: 3 × 5
#      id site             p1    p2 ind  
#   <int> <chr>         <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
# 1     1 AFD(1);AFD(2)  3.75  7.47 k1   
# 2     2 Acf(2)         5.37  7.98 k1   
# 3     5 ABC(7)         5.66  9.52 k2
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% 
  mutate(site_list = strsplit(site, ";")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(length(intersect(site_list,
                              unlist(strsplit(x = paste0(c(t(df1)), collapse=""), 
                                              split = ";")))) != 0) %>% 
  select(-site_list)
```

```
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   site              p1    p2
#>   <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 AFD(1);AFD(2);  3.75  7.47
#> 2 Acf(2);         5.37  7.98
#> 3 ABC(7);         5.66  9.52
```

##### Updated answer:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  rownames_to_column("id") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "k", values_to = "site") %>% 
  separate_rows(site, sep = ";") %>% 
  filter(site != "") %>% 
  select(-id) -> df1_k


df2 %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("id") %>% 
  separate_rows(site, sep = ";") %>% 
  full_join(., df1_k, by = c("site")) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  fill(k, .direction = "downup") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(id) & !is.na(k)) %>% 
  summarise(k = first(k), 
            site = paste0(site, collapse = ";"),
            p1 = first(p1),
            p2 = first(p2), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  select(-id)
```

```
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   k     site              p1    p2
#>   <chr> <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 k1    AFD(1);AFD(2);  3.75  7.47
#> 2 k1    Acf(2);         5.37  7.98
#> 3 k2    ABC(7);         5.66  9.52
```

Comment: Hi @M--, thank you! this gets me closer to my desired outcome,  but the first column from my ```outcome``` object, called ```k```, is missing.

Comment: @Wera yea, I just realized that (I usually don't read the whole question, sorry :). Working on it.